# Azure authentication issue - Exception while fetching current subscription - Azure.getCurrentSubscription()

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory

I'm facing the below exceptions while calling Azure.getCurrentSubscription(): Rarely we are getting 'Exception 1' and most of the time we get 'Exception 2'.

**Enviornment**:
Using Azure Java SDK: version azure-1.5.0

We created the AD Application and service principal and used the following IDs like Subscription ID, Tenant ID, Client ID, and Application Key to connect to Azure.getCurrentSubscription()

**By referring**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#certificates-and-secrets

*Note*: We haven't configured the App key with Certificates, only the plain client secret.

**Code sample**:

```
ApplicationTokenCredentials credentials = new ApplicationTokenCredentials(infoProps.getProperty("ClientID"), infoProps.getProperty("TenantID"), infoProps.getProperty("AppKey"), AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
Azure azureObj =
Azure.authenticate(credentials).withSubscription(infoProps.getProperty("SubscriptionID"));
azureObj.getCurrentSubscription();
```

**Exception 1**.

```
ERROR **com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext** - [Correlation ID: c7b9459f-1e11-4ded-889a-3bb1dd096855] **Request to acquire token failed**.
com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationException: {}
at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AdalTokenRequest.executeOAuthRequestAndProcessResponse(AdalTokenRequest.java:107)
at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext.acquireTokenCommon(AuthenticationContext.java:818)
at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext.access$100(AuthenticationContext.java:66)
at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext$1.call(AuthenticationContext.java:174)
at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext$1.call(AuthenticationContext.java:163)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationException: {}
at rx.exceptions.Exceptions.propagate(Exceptions.java:57)
at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.blockForSingle(BlockingObservable.java:463)
at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.last(BlockingObservable.java:226)
at com.microsoft.azure.management.resources.fluentcore.arm.collection.implementation.SupportsGettingByIdImpl.getById(SupportsGettingByIdImpl.java:22)
at com.microsoft.azure.management.Azure.getCurrentSubscription(Azure.java:416)
```

**Exception 2**.

```
INFO com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.**AuthenticationAuthority** - [Correlation ID: 1cb05385-b261-4977-8d75-55c24dd002a8] Instance discovery was successful
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.**SSLHandshakeException**: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at rx.exceptions.Exceptions.propagate(Exceptions.java:57)
at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.blockForSingle(BlockingObservable.java:463)
at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.last(BlockingObservable.java:226)
at com.microsoft.azure.management.resources.fluentcore.arm.collection.implementation.SupportsGettingByIdImpl.getById(SupportsGettingByIdImpl.java:22)
at com.microsoft.azure.management.Azure.getCurrentSubscription(Azure.java:416)

Caused by: **javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException**: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:241)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:198)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.buildConnection(RealConnection.java:174)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:114)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:193)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:129)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:98)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:109)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:124)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at com.microsoft.rest.retry.RetryHandler.intercept(RetryHandler.java:75)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at com.microsoft.rest.interceptors.CustomHeadersInterceptor.intercept(CustomHeadersInterceptor.java:140)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at com.microsoft.rest.interceptors.UserAgentInterceptor.intercept(UserAgentInterceptor.java:83)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at com.microsoft.azure.credentials.AzureTokenCredentialsInterceptor.intercept(AzureTokenCredentialsInterceptor.java:40)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at com.microsoft.azure.management.resources.fluentcore.utils.ResourceManagerThrottlingInterceptor.intercept(ResourceManagerThrottlingInterceptor.java:43)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at com.microsoft.azure.management.resources.fluentcore.utils.ProviderRegistrationInterceptor.intercept(ProviderRegistrationInterceptor.java:43)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at com.microsoft.rest.interceptors.BaseUrlHandler.intercept(BaseUrlHandler.java:43)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at com.microsoft.rest.interceptors.RequestIdHeaderInterceptor.intercept(RequestIdHeaderInterceptor.java:29)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:170)
at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:60)
at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:174)
at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$RequestArbiter.request(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:171)
at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:211)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.setProducer(OnSubscribeMap.java:102)
at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:152)
at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:138)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10256)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10256)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10256)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10256)
at rx.internal.operators.DeferredScalarSubscriber.subscribeTo(DeferredScalarSubscriber.java:153)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeTakeLastOne.call(OnSubscribeTakeLastOne.java:32)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeTakeLastOne.call(OnSubscribeTakeLastOne.java:22)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10352)
at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10319)
at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.blockForSingle(BlockingObservable.java:443)
... 67 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
... 145 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
... 151 more
```